# Jetpack Compose Composables/Widget Catalog

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Sorry to disturb but I have been searching for some time now and have not yet found a good place to see the widget catalog of Jetpack compose like the one used for Flutter. I want something where there is some kind of reference table or something that helps senior devs get up to speed in a glance or some short videos/demos just so that we get a feeling what is possible. The following links helped me get up to speed really fast when I wanted to learn Flutter and a similar thing for Compose would be great for intermediate/senior devs to get a very quick jumpstart.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets

Widget of the week
https://youtu.be/b_sQ9bMltGU

Comment: https://material.io/blog/jetpack-compose-catalog

Answer (score 1):

I found this, but, keep in mind that community is sharing composables, not sure if any official site (a google's one) about it.

https://composables.co/

They're preparing a ebook and waiting to more composables to de shared there.